# Can you give a technique to solve this integral?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I have to solve $$ \int_{0} ^{\infty} e^{-x^{2} - \frac{t^{2}}{x^{2}}} dx  $$

This is a standard integral in the treatment of improper integrals in many books but I haven't figured how to get the answer. The book I'm using (Elements of Real Analysis by Bartle) indicates to show that if
$$ G(t)=\int_{0} ^{\infty} e^{-x^{2} - \frac{t^{2}}{x^{2}}} dx  $$
then $G'(t)= 2G(t).$ Which I did very easily, but I don't know how that helps. I tried to use the standard techniques that involve computing the square of the integral with a change to polar coordinates but I couldn't make much progress with that. Any suggestions? Feel free to post a solution.

UPDATE
Sorry, I made a little algebra mistake, this should be $G'(t)= -2G(t)$ instead,  but the technique that's shown below still works, thanks for your answers.

Comment: If $G'(t) = 2 G(t)$, then $G(t) = A e^{2t}$..

Comment: @nicomezi Fair haha, but I'm not sure what else to say lol.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $G'(t)=2G(t)$, then this is just a separable ODE. Hence, we get:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
G'(t)=2G(t)\\
\frac{G'(t)}{G(t)}=2\\
\ln(G(t))=2t+C\\
G(t)=e^Ce^{2t}\\
G(0)=e^C=\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2}dx=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Comment: You're missing a $\tfrac12$ factor.

Comment: @J.G. Thanks for this!

Answer (score 5):

Here's another technique that doesn't require the ODE. Since the integrand is even, the integral is $\tfrac12\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-(x-|t|/x)^2-2|t|}dx$. With [Glasser's master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glasser%27s_master_theorem) this becomes $\tfrac12\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-u^2-2|t|}du=\tfrac12\sqrt{\pi}e^{-2|t|}$.

Comment: I also had Glasser's master theorem in mind. It's such an incredibly useful tool.

Answer (score 1):

Solution is $G(t)=Ae^{-2t}$  Use $G(0)=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$ to get $A$.

Comment: In the original statement $G(t)=G(-t)$.